# How to Sync Google Sheets spreadsheet with the Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-sheets, google-drive-api, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know if there's any solution to integrate Google Sheets spreadsheet with a Firebase database.

The use case is having a spreadsheet file stored in Google Drive, where I want to automatically sync data with the Firebase database (JSON format), and upon updating the spreadsheet file, I want Firebase to refresh and update the data stored.

Comment: Did anyone find the solution for this ?

Comment: @Awani What is the programming language that you are using?

Comment: This could be easily done with google apps script.

Comment: Agreed with you @Morfinismo.

Comment: @Awani does my solution answer your question?

Comment: @Joe this all example is talking about real time database but I am not using real time database to store information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with you @Morfinismo. You might need to listen to edit event from the scripts and then communicate with the firebase from there

```
/**
 * The event handler triggered when editing the spreadsheet.
 * @param {Event} e The onEdit event.
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  // update firebase from here
}
```

For more information on setting up googlescript check
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

For more information on connecting googlescript with firebase check
https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase

Comment: Hey abubakri ,. I believe that back then this solution wasn't possible.  thanks for the comment.

Comment: Anytime @mesmed. We are together in this

Answer (score 1):

This seems to outline the solution: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/sheets-to-firebase-33132e31935b

As described in the blog post, the 2 will be populated with the same data and seamlessly update as changes are made.